# javascript restore style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to see a specific div on full-screen and change style and for this, I used this function:

```
$(function () {
  $('#trigger').click(function () {
      var screenres = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
      document.getElementById("map").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      if (screenres == "1920x1080") {
          document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "1000px";
      }
      if (screenres == "1366x768") {
          document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "600px";
      }     
  });
}
```

The style is changed but it doesn't return to its former state. For example before full-screen;  the map div's height:300px  after the full-screen its value 1000px.

How can I return first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping track of the old size (I modified the code so that it will operate on the clicked element itself - feel free to modify it back to change the size of whatever map element you had before):

```
     var resizer = function (event) {
           var self = event.currentTarget;

           var prevw = $(self).width();
           var prevh = $(self).height();

           var screenres = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
           document.getElementById("trigger").style.backgroundColor = "white";
           if (screenres == "1920x1080") {
               document.getElementById("trigger").style.height = "1000px";
           }
           else if (screenres == "1600x900") {
               document.getElementById("trigger").style.height = "600px";
           }

           $(this).one('click',function(){

                   document.getElementById("trigger").style.width = prevw;
                   document.getElementById("trigger").style.height = prevh;
                  $(this).one('click',resizer);
           });

    };
    $('#trigger').one('click', resizer);
```

Comment: In your resizer function, where is `event` defined?

Comment: The code works like that anyway - but technically, you are right, it may break on some browsers such as older IE in which the magic word 'event' maps to window.event instead of automagically mapping to the passed event. So indeed you are right, technically I made a mistake and I should have defined one parameter of event in the resizer's function() parameter, since it is customary to define event handlers with one argument specifying the passed event object- I've slightly edited my solution to reflect that, changing function() to function (event). Great catch jfriend00!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {
var DivHeight = document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height;

// Use this DivHeight  whenever you want uese, you can also get it using jquery $("#map_canvas").height();

            $('#trigger').click(function () {
                var screenres = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
                document.getElementById("map").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                if (screenres == "1920x1080") {
                    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "1000px";
                }
                if (screenres == "1366x768") {
                    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "600px";
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown here will only run in two exact screen sizes.  Most the time, the viewer's screen won't match either of your two `if` statements so no width will be set.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#trigger').click(function () {
      document.getElementById("map").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      if (screen.height >= 1920) {
          document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "1000px";
      } else {
          document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "600px";
      }     
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default styles via a CSS selectors:

```
#trigger {
  height: 300px;
}
```

And after you return to the normal (default) state, you simply clear the `style` Attribute:

```
$('#trigger').attr("style", "");
```

Comment: I think this would only work if the style was inline, not from the CSS

Answer (score 0):

You gotta get dynamic. Use a jquery to get the dynamic width of your map before the if call, and then simply adjust your if statements; but I wouldn't do it based on specific map_canvas heights; all browsers and window sizes are variable on client side. Do something like
  function () {
  var divHeight = document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height;

$("#map_canvas").height();

```
        $('#trigger').click(function () {
            var screenres = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
            document.getElementById("map").style.backgroundColor = "white";
            if (screenres == "1920x1080") {
                document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "1000px";
            }
            if (screenres == "1366x768") {
                document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = "600px";
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a more general solution that you can use to change an attribute of a node and restore the previous value of that attribute. Supports JQuery and plain javascript:

```
function attributeMutation (node) {
  this.node = node;
  this.isJQuery = (Object.prototype.toString.call(node) === "[object Array]");
  this.store = {};             
}

attributeMutation.prototype.change = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  return this;
}

attributeMutation.prototype.to = function (value) {
  if (this.isJQuery) {
    this.store[this.name] = this.node.attr(this.name);
    this.node.attr(this.name, value);
  } else {
    this.store[this.name] = this.node.getAttribute(this.name);
    this.node.setAttribute(this.name, value);
  }
}

attributeMutation.prototype.restore = function (name) {
  var currentValue;
  if (this.isJQuery) {
    currentValue = this.node.attr(name);
    this.node.attr(name, this.store[name]);
  } else {
    currentValue = this.node.getAttribute(name);
    this.node.setAttribute(name, this.store[name]);
  }
  this.store[name] = currentValue;
}
```

Usage is:

```
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas")
  , mapCanvasAttributes = new attributeMutation(mapCanvas)
  , screenres = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;

if (screenres == "1920x1080") {
  mapCanvasAttributes.change('height').to('1000px');
}
if (screenres == "1366x768") {
  mapCanvasAttributes.change('height').to('6000px');
}

// and to restore to the previous height
mapCanvasAttributes.restore('height');
```